Problema de Acceso al Terminal en NetBeans 19: Error 'Cannot invoke...' y Soluciones en Versiones Posteriores
¿Cuál podría ser la causa del problema que impide la escritura en la terminal de NetBeans 19 y provoca el cierre instantáneo cuando se intenta abrir mediante el botón "Create New Local Terminal Lab"?, me sale el siguiente error:

"Cannot invoke 'java.util.List.toArray(Object[])' because the return value of 'org.netbeans.modules.nativeexecution.NativeProcessInfo.getCommand()' is null"

Se ha confirmado que en las versiones posteriores de NetBeans (20 y 21) el problema no persiste.

¿Tenías una pregunta parecida días atrás? Tengo la certeza de que vi una pregunta similar hace una par de semanas.

Hola, Lee Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!. Podrías poner tú código para que sea mas fácil ayudarte a encontrar el motivo del error, también comprueba si estás inicializando tu List.

si es la misma pregunta, lo doy por solucionado este tema, ya he estado hablando con los desarrolladores de Netbeans y estan solucionando algunos problemas de Jakarta que hay en la ultima versión, me dieron acceso a una versión que todavia no ha salido, en realidad el problema era por los Jpa Controllers que en la version 21 no funcionaban, por lo que al volver a la version 19 me doy cuenta de que la terminal no funciona y allí empezó todo el problema, pero bueno he vuelto a la version 21 con la terminal funcionando y Jpa controllers funcionando.
Un saludo, ¡Hasta la próxima y buen hacking!
